# Unable to click on element in Safaridriver on MAC

Tags: xpath, junit, safari, selenium-webdriver

i have been assigned a task where i am supposed to use Safari Browser on MAC. I am able to launch Safari, and scripts are also fine upto some extent. 
Now i am supposed to click on button, and its inspected using "Xpath", so here i am unable to click on the button and the script is getting fail.
Now, if i inspect the same button using "Id", i am able to click the button and script is executed successfully.

Can anyone help me to know :
1. Why its not possible to detect element using xpath in Safari ?
2. Whats the possible solution to solve this issue ?

Environment : Safari Browser : 7, Selenium server : 2.41.0

Answer (score 0):

Stick to using id, name and CSS selectors.